# Google Analytics regular expression to indicate TODAY?

Tags: google, google-analytics

in Google Analytics version 5 (latest beta) there's an option to add a custom filter

I want to show only data of today.

Only Show -> Date -> Exactly matching ->

and then I have the option to fill in in regular expression on the location of

But what is the regular expression to indicate TODAY?

Answer (score 3):

The date in Google Analytics report is defined on the top right menu, where you can pick 'Today' as a choice.

I don't think either profile-level filters or Advanced Segments can be set on dates.

If that does't answer your question, I'd love to see a screenshot to see what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: Im trying to create a widget that shows the keywords that were used TODAY to access my site. I want this widget on my GA Dashboard, just because so I dont have to go to the top right menu an pick today as a choice :) (and I dont have an option to upload image here AFAIK)

Comment: This answer is correct; what you're looking for is not possible.

Comment: Ok I got what you were trying to do now, but unfortunately I still think it's impossible - Regular Expressions do not have the concept of time.

Answer (score 2):

I had a look at the new widgets and noticed that the date dimension can be selected and filtered but I couldn't find a way to add in any relative dates like (today etc). You can only use absolute dates in a 'Ymd' format (eg '20110421'). This could be used to build a month or year filter but you'd need to change it manually so would be quite a bit of a hassle.

You would be better off trying something based around the API to build out a dashboard that showed what you want. If you use Excel you could try out something like Excellent Analytics. It's an open source plugin that lets you pull data out of the API and there is an option for downloading today's data.